# In Cantor's Theorem, can the diagonal set D be empty?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, elementary-set-theory

**Cantor's Theorem:**

For any set $A, |P(A)| > |A|$. That is, the power set of any set $A$ has a strictly greater cardinality than set $A$.

**Proof of not surjection:**

Suppose that there is an onto $f : A → P(A)$. Let $D$ be defined as follows:

$D = \{x ∈ A\ |\ x \notin f(x)\}$.

Note that, $D ⊆ A$, hence $D ∈ P(A)$.
Since $f$ is onto, then there is an $x ∈ A$ such that $f(x) = D$. Now either $x ∈ D$ or $x \notin D$. If
$x ∈ D$, then $x \notin f(x)$ by definition of $D$. But $f(x) = D$, so $x \notin D$, a contradiction. If $x \notin D$, then $x ∈ f(x)$. But $f(x) = D$, so $x ∈ D$, a contradiction. In any case, a contradiction arises, hence the assumption that there is an $x ∈ A$ such that $f(x) = D$ is false. Hence $f$ cannot
be onto.

**My Question:**

What if $f(x)=\{x\}$? Then wouldn't $D$ be empty? Please tell me why this won't work.

Comment: Separately, why would $D=\emptyset$ be a problem? All we care about is that $D\subseteq A$ (and $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, so that's good), and $D\not\in ran(f)$ (note that this is different from $D\not\color{red}{\subseteq}ran(f)$) which the remainder of the argument will show.

Comment: If you had $f(x)=\{ x \}$, or indeed if you pick any $f : A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $x \in f(x)$ for all $x \in A$, then $D$ would be $\emptyset$, which is indeed an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ which is not in the range of $f$, which is what you are trying to construct.

Comment: If $D = \emptyset$, you get a contradiction. Also, if $D = A$, you get a contradiction. In fact, no matter what possibility you take for $D$, you get a contradiction. That's how this proof works: assuming $f$ is surjective, there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=D$ and then, no matter *what* $D$ is, you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a situation where reframing the argument helps clarify it: while the diagonal argument is generally presented as a proof by contradiction, it is really a **constructive** proof of the following result:

> For every set $A$ and function $f: A\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A)$, there is some $X\subseteq A$ such that $X\not\in ran(f)$.

Of course this implies the usual phrasing, that there is no surjection $A\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A)$, but in my experience it's often less mysterious to students. I think this is because it frees us from having to think about objects that we're actively trying to show don't exist; in some contexts this isn't particularly bad, but once we start looking at more abstract topics like set theory it can form a real impediment to understanding at first.

In fact, the diagonal argument describes an **explicit method** for getting such an $X$ from a given $f$: we just set $X=\{a\in A: a\not\in f(a)\}$. Let's call this the $\color{red}{\mbox{antidiagonal set}}$ associated to $f$.

Now let's think about things from this perspective. Fixing a set $A$, consider the "singletoning" function: $$f: a\mapsto\{a\}.$$ When we construct the corresponding antidiagonal set we get $\emptyset$, since $$\{a\in A: a\not\in f(a)\}=\{a\in A: a\not\in \{a\}\}=\emptyset.$$ But **this is fine**: we clearly have $\emptyset\not\in ran(f)$ as desired, since every element of $ran(f)$ is nonempty ($ran(f)$ consists exactly of the one-element subsets of $A$, and $\emptyset$ does not have one element).

So it's entirely possible that the diagonal construction, applied to a given $f$, yields the emptyset; however, that's fine, since in that case the emptyset will be one of the things $f$ misses in its range.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Whether $D$ is empty or not is irrelevant. All we need is $D \in P(A)$ (which is also true if it were empty) and so some $x \in A$ exists such that $f(x)=D$. This is all we use. *If* $D$ were empty, $x \notin D$ obviously and then we get a contradiction because we'd then conclude (as in the argument you have) that $x \in D$, and we still have the same solid contradiction ($x \in D$ **and** $x \notin D$ both would hold).

It makes no difference.

Comment: That makes sense... Thanks for your response!